# How to produce correct newlines in downloads from python web server

Tags: python, web-services, download

I am writing a web application in Python.  I need to generate a file to download.  Ideally, the file should consist of one item per line.  My question is: how can I produce the correct type of newline characters, so that the downloaded file works well for users running both Windows and Mac/Linux?

Right now, as a stopgap solution, I am separating the items with a space (at least there is a single notion of space on Windows and Linux/Mac!).  This is not too bad for my application, but is there a way to do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're generating the content on the fly, you could infer the client's platform by introspecting the *User-Agent* string on the incoming *HTTP* header and then treat newlines accordingly.

That is, if the *User-Agent* string indicates the client is using *Windows*, use `CR` + `LF` (`\r\n`) and if it indicates a *nix platform (*Linux*, *OS X*, etc.) then use just `LF` (`\r').

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

The type can also be supplied in the *HTTP* headers. That's via the header *Content-Type*. The value **text/plain** indicates a regular text file, and this is the default value for this header field.

However, there is nothing that tells the browser to "adapt newline format". The handling of raw text would be a combination of browser and platform specific. In some cases it might trigger a launch dialog, as well, to, say, load it in a text editor.

For a file downloaded on a given platform, the bigger question would be the support outside the browser, I think. i.e. in text editors and such, so it would be better to match the platform's preferred newline type in that case if you're dynamically generating the content.

If it's something *solely* meant to be rendered in a browser, then it might be worth considering rendering it in *HTML*, which is standards based (although even there, there can be browser/platform differences).

While there are multiple ways to achieve formatting, a linebreak in *HTML* can always be represented as `<br>` and `<p></p>` to denote a paragraph (usually with space surrounding it on top and bottom), so there's more consistency there. In that case it would be marked up when loading in a regular text editor, though, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: There is no way to tell the browser "this is a text file, please adapt newline format"?